# assign variable to radio button and multiply by user input in Text Field

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk, toast

I am new to Android. I am trying to create an app that will take the numerical data entered in a text field and multiply it by a value of a selected radio button. Does that make sense? basically, user inputs a number and I want to multiply that number by the value of the radio button. result would be a Toast (or anything else) that displays the calculated amount.

My question(s);

how do i assign a value to a radio button?
how do i link that value to Java?
How do I link both to a calculate button?
How do i make the Toast appear with the calculated data?

Comment: what you tried can share that

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the index:

```
int index = yourRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(yourRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()))
```

Then get the number from your test field and do your calculation.

You can also get the value itself, if you wish:

```
RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) yourRadioGroup.getChildAt(index);
String selectedValue= (String) btn.getText();
```